# A word to say "something that is not obvious to understand"?

Tags: word-request

I'm looking for an adjective defining "something that is not obvious to understand".

For example, in French, I would say "hermétique", which in English is synonym to airtight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I first thought of "subtle" (which has its equivalent in French: subtil) but I think you are looking for "abstruse", which is something that's hard to understand, something obscure. Do we have a context for that word?

Answer (score 3):

**Unintuitive** would describe something that is not immediately apparent, but requires some study to understand or master.

> Not intuitive, not easily graspable by intuition.
>
> https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/unintuitive

Answer (score 1):

Opaque would probably work fairly well.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few: complicated, confusing, ambiguous, blurred, obscure, perplexing.

I'd go with "[**unclear**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/unclear#unclear__1)" - *not obvious, definite, or easy to understand*

Answer (score 0):

I just remembered another word that fits what I had in mind:

"Cryptic": having a meaning that is mysterious or obscure.

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is helpful; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.